# Count array in repeated elements

Tags: python

I have the following array:

```
 CUSTOMER = ['MARIA', 'JOAO', 'MARIA', 'JOAO']
```

I would like to do the following count:

```
 {'MARIA': 2, 'JOAO': 2}
```

I tried using the `from collections import Counter` library, but counted each letter in the array

Comment: `Counter(CUSTOMER)` should do it.

Comment: Yes, it is Maria, sorry!

Comment: The second answer in the duplicated question, addresses your concerns.

Comment: To tell you why your attempt counted the letters instead, we would have to see the code you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> CUSTOMER = ['MARIA', 'JOAO', 'MARIA', 'JOAO']
>>> Counter(CUSTOMER)
Counter({'MARIA': 2, 'JOAO': 2})
```